# Working with an array and ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an array of objects. I want to be when you click on the link, I came through all the objects and displays them on the page, at using ajax

**run.js.erb**

```
$(function(){

  $("#next").click(function(){

    $.post(<%= EngineHelper.nextQuestion %>, function(data){
    $("#question").html(data);
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

But it does not work. in the script instead of <% = EngineHelper.nextQuestion%> substituted the current data array element. and I need to display the next array element

Comment: the ERB preprocessing is done only once on the page load. If you look at the source of your page, you will see there only one object serialized. So, you need to use ajax, or maybe put all the questions as json into javascript and then use javascript loops

Answer (score 0):

try converting it to jSON

so instead:

```
$.post(<%= EngineHelper.nextQuestion.to_json %>, function(data){
  $("#question").html(data);
});
```

hope it helps :)